# Identifying duplicate documents

Tags: document, 2007, development

The search results webpart has a boolean property which can be used to configure whether "duplicate" results should be returned.

Looking at documents, when is a **document A** considered to be a duplicate of **document B**? Does the content of the file need to be identical?

Also, is there a way to use the SharePoint Object Model to indentify duplicate documents?

Answer (score 2):

Only ½ an answer here (ill ask Lars Fastrup to opt in): I seem to remember from last time i looked at IFilters that the ifilter extract the text from the document and that the comparison is done by checking similarity of two texts. The keyword here being similar, not identical. How the this is determined im not sure...

For what i know the only thing the object model has to offer is the same as is exposed in the search web part: an FullTextSQLQuery has a boolean TrimDuplicates property, that lets you include duplicates or not.

hth
Anders Rask

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how the duplication is identified, but in my experience it works remarkably well. I have seen several cases in which very simlar documents were identified as duplicates. The content was almost identical but the formatting had been changed.